# Getting 'cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a button do something in another view controller. I made a delegate, added a function with a requirement of having an indexPath so I could use it to delete items in an array, but when I make a variable indexPath equal to IndexPath.self and try feeding it into the actual IBAction, it spits out the error shown in the title. Here is my code for my first view controller, where the IBAction and protocol is defined.

```
import UIKit

protocol ToDoItemCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didTapX(with indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class ToDoItemCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: ToDoItemCellDelegate?
    
    static let identifier = "ToDoItemCell"

    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "ToDoItemCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    

    
    @IBOutlet var xButton: UIButton!
    private var indexPath = IndexPath.self
    
    @IBAction func didTapX(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapX(with: indexPath)

    }
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are mistaking type for entity. You probably should read about that concept.

Comment: With `private var indexPath = IndexPath.self` you are defining a type and your delegate expects an entity.

Comment: oh, whoops! is there any way i would be able to use a default value of some kind for the condition? if i try to use IndexPath instead of indexPath, I get the same error, but it loops back into me not being able to actually create an entity to fill that requirement.

Comment: It doesn't "spit". It's telling you very clearly what _you_ are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken type and entity. Your delegate expects an entity and your var only provides a type. You stated in your comment that you do not need to provide any meaningfull value here so you have multiple possibilities:

- Remove the argument from the delegate:

  ```
  protocol ToDoItemCellDelegate: AnyObject {
      func didTapX()
  }
  ```
- or create a default value while calling the delegate and remove the property:

  ```
  @IBAction func didTapX(_ sender: UIButton) {
      delegate?.didTapX(with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
  }
  ```
- or assign a defalut to the property and use it while calling the delegate:

  ```
  private var indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
  ```

Comment: I decided to try removing the argument, but now I have the problem of not being able to create an indexPath for my function. I'm definitely unexperienced, but I can't figure out how to make a variable that's equal to the IndexPath of an array...

Comment: @KingNektus it´s hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. This answer is as precise as it can be with the information you provided.

Comment: Should I make another question altogether, then?

Comment: @KingNektus If it would change the premise of this question and answer - (what it most likely will) - it would be better to create a new question. In either case please add more detail to your question, what do you want to achieve with this? What is the purpose of this indexpath? Where do you want to get the path from?